# Invisible redirection (RewriteRule + Apache)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My goal is to redirect (invisibly) all requests beginning by `/example` to `/experiments/example`.
For example :

- /example -> /experiments/example (but stay /example in URL)
- /example/ -> /experiments/example/ (but stay /example/ in URL)
- /example/logo.png -> /experiments/example/logo.png (but stay
- /example/logo.png in URL)   /example/test/logo.png ->
- /experiments/example/test/logo.png (but stay /example/test/logo.png
  in URL)

Here is my .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example(\/.*)?$ experiments/example$1
```

It works ! But... only if the request ends with `/`.

- /example/ -> /experiments/example/ (stay /example/ in URL : Good !)
- /example -> /experiments/example (change to /experiments/example in URL : Not good !)

I tried a lots of things without success. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^example /experiments%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```